# The modelling of a massive particle in different reference frames

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Say there are two observers, A and B, A is at rest and B is moving at velocity c, both observers are sitting in different reference frames observing the same massive particle at $x = 0$. Both A and B are at the same location at time, $t = 0$. The physics is the same in both reference frames but what predictions do both observers make for the motion of the massive particle and the expectation values?

Comment: Is $c$ in question the speed of light? If so, you need special relavitity, which is incompatible with "ordinary" quantum mechanics. Also, there's a problem defining $B$, related to the fact that only a massless system can move at $c$, and such a system has no rest frame.

Answer (score 0):

> what predictions do both observers make for the motion of the massive particle and the expectation values?

A and B cannot be observers and move at velocity c by construction of the [four vectors](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=hyperphysics%20four%20vectors.) of the relativistic transformations

The quantum mechanical equations for the particles have to be the relativistic ones, Dirac and Klein Gordon, whose solutions are Lorentz invariant, so the QM predictions will be the same at each inertial frame A and B.

> The physics is the same in both reference frames but what predictions do both observers make for the motion of the massive particle and the expectation values?

By construction of the theory, which fits all known data, there cannot be a rest frame for the particle moving at c, it has to be a photon or another zero mass particle and there is no rest frame to observe from. If you are talking about velocities of a massive particle close to c, the mathematics of going to each other's center of mass is well understood and consistent using the Lorentz transformations.